# Kendo UI - Difference between observable, ObservableObject and Model

Tags: object, model, kendo-ui, observable

What are the differences between the observable, ObservableObject and Model?
Thank You.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Model inherits from ObservableObject which inherits from Observable.

- [Observable](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/observable) provides support for events - the bind, unbind and trigger methods.
- [ObservableObject](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/observableobject) provides change tracking. Used by the DataSource and the MVVM framework.
- [Model](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/model) provides identity (via the `id` field) and field definition. Used by the DataSource when `schema.model` is set.

Comment: So, Model and ObservableObject are one the same, while Observable is something totally different?

Comment: Model is a superset of ObservableObject.

Comment: Can I define the custom callback function in Model as I do in the observable object?

Comment: This is worth a new question with clarification and sample code.

Comment: Ok. Will prepare after some more research. Thank You for answers.