# Kendo-UI data-bind to function is not working

Tags: javascript, html, mvvm, kendo-ui

I have following working code using Kendo UI MVVM  - [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ZMdA/11/)

Here there is a binding in the template for the checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" name="selection" data-bind="checked: isChecked"/>
```

It is bound to `isChecked` property of the model.

Now I need to show an alert when user clicks on the checkbox by alerting the checked / unchecked state and Name  of user.

I tried with data-bind="checked: showAlert()" but that didnt work.

How can we achieve this?

[image]

**BODY**

```
<script id="selection-table-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: age"></td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="selection" data-bind="checked: isChecked"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</script>

<script id="row-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <tr data-bind="visible: isChecked">
        <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: age"></td>
    </tr>
</script>

<table id="selectionTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-template="selection-table-template" data-bind="source: employees"/>
</table>

<br />
<hr />

<table id="resultTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-template="row-template" data-bind="source: employees"/>
</table>
```

**Javascript**

```
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
    employees: [
        { name: "Lijo", age: "28", isChecked: true },
        { name: "Binu", age: "33", isChecked: true },
        { name: "Kiran", age: "29", isChecked: true }
    ] 
});


$(document).ready(function () {
    kendo.bind($("body"), viewModel);
});
```

**REFERENCES**

1. [How to display only selected records in the result table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21982668/how-to-display-only-selected-records-in-the-result-table)
2. [MVVM / Custom binding](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/mvvm/custom.html)
3. [MVVM / Event binding](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/mvvm/event.html)
4. [Kendo MVVM Overview](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/framework/mvvm/overview)
5. [Value binding](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/framework/mvvm/bindings/value)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either data-bind the change event:

Html:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="selection" 
data-bind="checked: isChecked, events: { change: printIsChecked }"/>
```

View model:

```
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
    employees: [{
        name: "Lijo",
        age: "28",
        isChecked: true
    }, {
        name: "Binu",
        age: "33",
        isChecked: true
    }, {
        name: "Kiran",
        age: "29",
        isChecked: true
    }],
    printIsChecked: function(e) {
        $("#out2").html("via event-binding on input: " + e.data.name + " is checked: " + e.data.isChecked);
    }
});
```

or bind a change event handler to the observable (without changing your Html):

```
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
    employees: [{
        name: "Lijo",
        age: "28",
        isChecked: true
    }, {
        name: "Binu",
        age: "33",
        isChecked: true
    }, {
        name: "Kiran",
        age: "29",
        isChecked: true
    }],
    printIsChecked: function (e) {
        var changedItem = e.items[0];

        // note: might need to check e.field === "isChecked" 
        // if other fields might change or if you add/remove items from employees
        $("#out").html("via Observable.change: " + changedItem.name + " is checked: " + changedItem.isChecked);
    }
});  
viewModel.employees.bind("change", viewModel.printIsChecked);
```

([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/4ZMdA/12/))